# How to collaborate on a single android studio project?

Tags: android-studio

My friend and I are working on a project and need a way to collaborate. Is there a service like google docs for Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is to use some VCS (version control system). Version Control Systems lets you manage project and allows to collaborate.

There are many VCSs like git, Mercurial, CVS and [many many more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software). Android Studio has inbuilt support for *GIT, CVS, Mercurial, Subversion*. So you can go for any of those to work with android studio. Nowadays most used and popular VCS is **GIT**. And I personally recommend it.

There are many websites which allows you to create, maintain and collaborate online project using git.
Here are few of them:

- [Github](https://github.com/)
- [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

Before start using git, it is advised to go through [GIT guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).

Answer (score 3):

As HBB20 said, the classical option is to use a version control system (such as **GIT**).

However, if you want real time interactions as you would get in google doc (I believe it is called collaborative coding), there is a [Floobits plugin](https://github.com/Floobits/floobits-intellij) for IntelliJ's IDE and in particular Android Studio.

You can watch two videos explaining how to set up and use the plugin on [IntelliJ's blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/touring-plugins-floobits/).

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio Project in  [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)  then install a plugin "Code With Me"
this plugin allows pair programming, It enables you to share the currently opened project in your IDE with others, and work on it together in real-time.